# FileUpload Using Ajax In ASP.NET With C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to upload images using FileUpload without postback(using Ajax).I tried many examples.But in all postback is coming or they are using PHP.Can anyone help me to do single file upload or multi file upload using ajax in ASP.Net with C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SWFUpload

http://demo.swfupload.org/v220beta3/simpledemo/index.php

http://swfupload.org/

Javascript and Flash, there's no post-back :) and there's .NET implementations available on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you find this useful.

http://aspalliance.com/1442_Building_AJAX_Enabled_File_Uploading_System_with_Progress_Bar_Using_ASPNET_20.all

It's using asp.net and ajax.

Answer (score 1):

As the others say you can't do it completely without a postback but you can add some nice ajax functionality around the process. Steve Sanderson has written a good walkthrough here:

http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

Comment: That's an MVC implementation of SWF Upload, if he's using WebForms which most people are at the moment he will have a few issues porting the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally used this: [Ajax Uploader](http://ajaxuploader.com/) - Not free mind you but pretty decent.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ajax Uploader](http://ajaxuploader.com) too. It works great for my projects and it allows you to upload files to web server without refreshing the page.

Here is a [demo page](http://ajaxuploader.com/demo/Ajax-based-user-profile.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a ajax file upload. The components that you see either use flash swfupload or a hidden iframe that they post a form to that give the impression it is happening in an ajax manner. There are many plugins avaiable to help you do this. My favourite is [this](http://jquery.webunity.nl/) that uses jquery and swfupload

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can access the contents of a file input field through JS. This is because of security concerns. Though what you CAN do is to create an iframe and from a button submit only that iframe which again can contain your file input field...

This would give the "impression" of an Ajax File Upload control...

Answer (score 0):

as other guys said,file upload needs postback.In any update panel ,you should register file upload control as postbackcontrol to scriptmanager.Also you may [look telerik upload control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) to have an idea for what it should be.