# file upload using ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asyncfileupload

file upload using ajax by retaining all the other information in the page.

Comment: File upload with ajax (xmlhttprequest) is not possible. There are some other methods. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336446/fileupload-using-ajax-in-asp-net-with-c. (edit) A comment on this link says it's for mvc specifically: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plug-in for this, works pretty good (and is a pure JavaScript/jQuery solution).

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net mvc file upload ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780241/asp-net-mvc-file-upload-ajax-post)

[How can I upload a file via ASP.NET MVC and show a progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977995/how-can-i-upload-a-file-via-asp-net-mvc-and-show-a-progress-bar)

http://www.uploadify.com/

hope this helps