# Ajax File Upload (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Is it possible to upload a (pdf) file using HTML5 + Ajax + jQuery + C# ?

I need to upload a file w/o reloading the page.

As I'm not a web developer, please 'keep it simple' answering the question.:)

Comment: Yes, you can! Plenty of AJAX upload tutorials out there! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336446/fileupload-using-ajax-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *jquery.form* plugin, it's very simple to do what you want:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form" action="upload_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" size="60" name="file">
     <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>

<div id="progress">
     <div id="bar"></div>
     <div id="percent">0%</div >
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = {
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#progress").show();
            //clear everything
            $("#bar").width('0%');
            $("#message").html("");
            $("#percent").html("0%");
        },
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            $("#bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
            $("#percent").html(percentComplete + '%');

        },
        success: function () {
            $("#bar").width('100%');
            $("#percent").html('100%');

        },
        complete: function (response) {
            $("#message").html("<font color='green'>" + response.responseText + "</font>");
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

        }

    };

    $("#form").ajaxForm(options);

});
```

This will also give you a nice progress bar which you can style however you want.

[**Plugin page**](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: Forgot to mention that the file to upload is chosen by user and I can only use Javascript / jQuery, can't change the .cshtml file.

Comment: How do I handle the submission on the server side (using C#) ?

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs I'm sorry, but I can't answer on that. Don't know any C#, but do you not know how to handle submission in general or does the file simply not reach the file handling page?

Comment: Example: $.get("/.../CallbackMethod/", [parameters], function (json) {...}, "json");

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxForm'

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit'

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs are you sure you added all the necessary scripts (both jQuery library and the form plugin *before* you called the function)?

Answer (score 0):

We have a ASP.NET uploader written in c#+ajax in our  GPL package which you can find here:

https://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/downloads/list